# Swift WebKitView inside UITableViewCell - Cell reloads webkit view every time it comes on screen

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, webkit

I'm trying to load a WebKitView inside a UITableViewCell. Although the cell is repeating, I always only load one cell of this type. The WebKitView loads an embedded youtube video URL.

So currently, the code is working, but there is an issue that is causing me to second guess my code, and wonder if there is something I'm missing.

The behavior is as follows:
1. The table loads all cells properly, with no issues
2. The cell containing the web kit view loads properly, and the embedded youtube video link loads properly in the cell. The video is able to play / go full screen, and seems to be working just fine.

Here's where the problem starts:
3. As I scroll up and down through the table cells, every time the video cell comes on screen, there is a significant lag spike, and I can tell that the cell is reloaded as there is a print statement inside cellForRowAt that is printing every time.
4. An error is produced along with the print statement. The error is as follows:

```
2018-05-17 08:46:07.305058-0500 Storefront[15267:9513857] WF: 
_WebFilterIsActive returning: NO
2018-05-17 08:46:08.817680-0500 Storefront[15267:9513857] WF: 
_userSettingsForUser mobile: {
filterBlacklist =     (
);
filterWhitelist =     (
);
restrictWeb = 1;
useContentFilter = 0;
useContentFilterOverrides = 0;
whitelistEnabled = 0;
}
```

I did some research on the error specifically, and from what I've gathered it's caused by the secure URL that I specified loading insecure content. This is a youtube url, so this is very strange.

I tried adding youtube.com to my NSExceptionDomains inside my plist, with no change. However, from my research, I'm not convinced that the error being printed is related to the lag I'm experiencing, and the reloading of the webkitview every time it comes on screen. It must be something to do with how using a reusable cell containing a webkitview interacts with the cell loading.

Here's my cellForRow code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if product.productHasVideo == true {
        let cell = tableView.deque(VideoTableViewCell.self, configureFrom: self.product, at: indexPath)
        if let id = product.embededYoutubeVideoId {
            print("has id")
            if let url = URL(string: "https://www.youtube.com/embed/\(id)") {
                let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
                cell.videoWebKitView.load(urlRequest)
            }
        } else {
            print("no id")
        }
        return cell
    } else {
        return UITableViewCell()
    }
}
```

}

Any thoughts or ideas? Thanks.

EDIT:
I thought to try removing the entire url loading section from the code and just load the webkit view. This was successful. The cell loaded the webkitview, but never loaded a URL. I still received the same error listed above, and the same lag listed above, so the issue definately has nothing to do with my plist or youtube or the URL I'm specifying.

Here is the code inside the tableViewCell:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class VideoTableViewCell: UITableViewCell, ViewModelConfigurable {

typealias ViewModelType = ProductViewModel

var viewModel: ViewModelType?
@IBOutlet var videoWebKitView: WKWebView!

func configureFrom(_ viewModel: ViewModelType) {
    self.viewModel = viewModel


}

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

}
```

Comment: What's your `prepareForReuse()` inside the custom `UITableViewCell` look like?

Comment: I did a couple edits just now. My entire custom tableviewcell code is now in the question. It looks like im not currently specifying anything for prepareForReuse()

Comment: Did you try to put cell.videoWebKitView.load(urlRequest) into DispatchQueue.main.async ?

Comment: Just tried it. No change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implementation of `UITableView` is making cells reusable, it is not holding all cells always, it makes how many it will fit on screen +/- some buffer. When You scroll it is making table view reuse cells -> reloading happens.

You can use just `UIScrollView` to instantiate custom views and then it is up to You when You want to destroy/reuse/remove them.

Comment: Makes sense. Unfortunately I'm pretty locked into using the table view. I'm going to try and load the video thumbnail image into the cell, and if the user taps it, load the video in a pop up view.

Comment: @AlexRitter - good idea. If my answer helped, remember to “tick” it:)

Comment: I will - still doing some more testing. After entirely stripping away the cell and reverting to the previous state of the table, I found that the issue was still happening, I was just not aware of it, as not many of my products have videos. The real issue is stemming from an NSAttributedString attempting to interpret the full youtube video embed code in my product's description.

Comment: After extensive testing, I found that the lag I experienced and the error message produced were in no way related to this question. However - @Preetygeek is correct in that the cells are being reloaded each and every time they go on/off the screen. As such, his suggestion for this question is correct. However, for my particular application - once the real cause of the lag and error message had been addressed, I found the reloading of the webkitview to not be bothersome at all, and works just fine with no lag.